# SQL: update request - sum quantity of rows depending on columns, delete old copies

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Problem**

I have the following situation:
When user on my website isn't logged in, he can add products to shopcart. But when he clicks on 'BUY' button in shopcart info page, he should login to proceed to checkout and finalize the order. This is the main logic here...

So imagine, user has 2 products and isn't logged in yet (he already has account on site). Then, he will make login, and he already has exact same 2 products on account, but with different quantities.

**Target:**

I want to make a sum of similar products in shopcart table, and then delete copies of similar products.

---

**Sql table**

```
Id            Qt    user_id    outer_user_id

product-1     1       22            NULL
product-1     3       NULL          45
product-2     1       NULL          45
product-2     2       22            NULL
product-2     5       27            NULL
```

I want the following result when user just logged in:

```
Id            Qt   user_id     outer_user_id

product-1     4      22            NULL
product-2     3      22            NULL
product-2     5      27            NULL

-- outer user with outer_user_id = 45 will login as inner user with user_id = 22
```

---

As you see, I want to create unique product from multiple similar, and sum their quantity. How can I do it in SQL Server database with request? **Thank You!**

**NOTE:** Query should update table and delete some rows, not selecting the results.

Comment: You want a group by statement    `select Id,sum(Qt) group by Id`

Comment: How do you define which product is older? or just deleting all but one that should be updated is enough?

Comment: @ChrisFlynn I think that it is only part of the answer since the OP is also asking to update and delete

Comment: I don't want to `SELECT`, but to `UPDATE` table (look at the title of question)

Comment: @JorgeCampos, exactly

Comment: What else is in that table, any IDENTITY ID's or similar? You could update them all, and then remove the newest, if you have a column to determine what the newest is etc.

Comment: @Leonidas199x, I updated my question: there is a user_id and also outer_user_id

Comment: Table also has `date_added` column which indicates, when the product was added to DB... It's done through PHP , so if it's not possible in SQL I should do it in PHP then  :))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the code snippet: Used a update statement and  CTE to delete the duplicate records. I just grouped by id for example but for your case you need to group by user_id and product_Id

```
 Create table #temp(id int , dvalue int)

Insert into #temp(id,dvalue) values(1,10)
Insert into #temp(id,dvalue) values(1,2)
Insert into #temp(id,dvalue) values(1,3)
Insert into #temp(id,dvalue) values(2,10)
Insert into #temp(id,dvalue) values(2,1)
Insert into #temp(id,dvalue) values(2,1)

select * from #temp

Update t1 set t1.dvalue=(select sum(dvalue) from #temp t group by id having 
t.id=t1.id) from #temp t1;

WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id order by dvalue) AS RN
FROM #temp
)

DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN<>1
```

I just used some other tables and column name - Hope its helps you.

Comment: I was trying to figure out a way without a temp table (a merge maybe). but this might be the best way.

Comment: Yeah, you do the same on normal table. @Quark

Comment: Wait, I have some problems changing table depending only on user_id = 22 and outer_user_id = 45...

Comment: I just can't figure out how to group it by these id's

Comment: @RohitPadma, how can I group by user_id like on table in question? I just can't figure it out... First of all, we can take rows where `outer_user_id=45 `and set `user_id=22, outer_user_id=NULL`, so we can get rid of outer_user_id... But after that I just can't understand how to make sum of all `Qt` where `user_id=22` and just group it all in update result, leaving only unique rows. Can u help me?

Comment: @MaxWater : once you get rid of outer_user_id . I am bad at explaining . . You can refer the below Query.Hope its help you. :)                                                                            

                                                                                                         
 Update p1 set p1.dvalue=(select sum(dvalue) from #product p group by id,UserID having 
p.id=p1.id and p.UserID=p1.UserID) from #Product p1;

WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id,userid order by dvalue) AS RN
FROM #product
)

DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN<>1

Comment: I figured it out, thank you. I've used your code, but changed it a bit. I'll add an update text to your answer soon, and will check as solution, ok?

Comment: @MaxWater  yeah sure ! :)